# Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string at (1)

Tags: fortran, format

Getting this error while trying to compile a code.

code:

```
    write(luttyo, 11) nargs 


    11    format('*** Too many arguments to SUPREM (',i1,') Run as:'/,'sup3 [outfil [infill ] ]')
      stop
23000 continue
```

compiler error:

> *** Too many arguments to SUPREM (',i1,') Run
>   as:'/,'sup3 [outfil [infill ] ]')
>                                                              1 Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string at (1)

Can anybody help me in rectifying this error?

Comment: Welcome. Be sure to take the [Tour] and see [ask]. Please use the formatting to make your post more readable and avoid thinks like "Plz".

Comment: It appears to me your line is just too long. Are you using fixed form source? What is the extension of your source file? How are you compiling it?

Comment: I used continuation mark (&) to divide my statement..but couldn't compile the code without error..its a Fortran source code (text/x-fortran)...i m basically trying to install SUPREM3 Software n when i use "make install" command, in the suprem folder the error points to the file named "sup3.f"

Comment: Please read my answer in the link. A .f file is a *fixed-form* Fortran source file and  you need to put the `&` on the new line in the fifth column. You really should read more about Fortran fixed form. See an example at  http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fixed+form+layout